# Ao navegar página recebe valor inesperado do $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

Tenho uma página com Menu Dinâmico acessando a página de permissões do usuário, esta funcionando bem exceto que o valor da `SESSION` independentemente de qual usuário seja, sempre passa o conteúdo de campo do último registro lido e não da página realmente a ser acessada.

Exemplo:

PAGINA MENU  - ( Iniciando a sessão )

```
session_start();
if((!isset ($_SESSION['login']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['senha']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['nome']) == true))
{
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    unset($_SESSION['senha']);
    unset($_SESSION['nome']);  
    header('location:index.php');
    }   

    $login    = $_SESSION['login'];
    $senha    = $_SESSION['senha'];
    $nome     = $_SESSION['nome'];
    $operacao = $_SESSION['per_operacao'];
```

Ainda na pagina `MENU`  ( Montando o menu a partir de uma tabela, acessando a Página referida (Usuário)  e passando os dados ( operações ) .

```
   <li><a href="MenuPrincipal.php"><?php echo $lSub['mod_descricao'];?></a>   
                <ul class="submenu-2">   
           <?php   
                $seleciona_rotina = pg_query("SELECT * FROM Menu_rotina WHERE id_modulo = '$idmod'"); 

            if(pg_num_rows($seleciona_rotina) == 0) { 
                } else {   
                while($sSub = pg_fetch_array($seleciona_rotina)){
                  $_SESSION['per_operacao']=$sSub['per_operacao'];
                   echo($_SESSION['per_operacao']);     // ( conteúdo: 1.2.3.4.5 )
            ?> 
            <li>   <a href="<?php echo $sSub['per_pagina']?>"><?php echo $sSub['gpo_descricao'];?></a>    
                   <?php }?>
    </li>
   <?php }?>
</ul>
   <?php }?>
   </li>
```

Até aqui tudo bem,  aponta o menu escolhido com suas respetivas permissões ( Rotinas que o usuário teria acesso  ) , e o campo `per_operações = 1.2.3.4.5.`,  ( até aqui esta ótimo) .

PÁGINA USUÁRIO:  ( Acesso a página e iniciando a sessão )

```
<?php

     session_start(); // sempre que usarmos as sessions devemos chamar esse codigo sempre no inicio do script
     if(isset($_SESSION['per_operacao'])){// verifica se existe a varavel session
     $operacao['per_operacao']=$_SESSION['per_operacao']; // passa o valor da variavel session para outra variavel so que uma variavel dentro do mesmo arquivo
     $operacao=$_SESSION['per_operacao']; // passa o valor da variavel session par a outra variavel so que uma variavel dentro do mesmo arquivo
     echo($_SESSION['per_operacao']);   //  ( conteúdo: 0.0.1.0.1 )
     }else{
     echo("vc não passou pelo arquivo anterior" );
}

 ?>
```

Ocorre o seguinte:  aqui ele deveria me mostrar o conteúdo do campo `per_operação` igual ao passado pela página "menu principal", e já detetei que independentemente de quantos registros tenha na tabela `permissao`, esta sendo tratado corretamente no `Menuprinciapl.PHP`,  mas está sempre passando o conteúdo do último registro para o `Usuario.php`.

Espero ter sido claro, pelo pouco entendimento que tenho, mas desde já fica aqui meus agradecimentos pela atenção dispensadas por todos, e parabéns pela ajuda que tem sido dada a muitos colegas e a mim também.

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, mas você não precisa de `!isset ($_SESSION['login']) == true`. isset já retorna `true` ou `false`, então basta usar `if( !isset ( $_SESSION['login'] ) and ...` e os outros !isset

Comment: Tem mais problemas: cadê o "die" ou "exit" depois do location? O código continua sendo executado, mesmo depois do redirect, se não tiver exit ou die (pode ser usado intencionalmente, mas é arriscado). Outra coisa: se nenhuma das variáveis está setada, que é o teste do IF, qual o sentido de dar `unset`? A não ser que você vá usar OR em vez do AND. Aí pode ser, se uma estiver vazia, "unseta" o resto.

Answer (score 0):

Para entender melhor o que está acontecendo, você precisa entender como funcionam as sessões no php.

De forma resumida, quando um usuário acessa o seu site, ele ganha um identificador único (o id da sessão) que é salvo em um cookie. Quando você chama a função `session_start`, o php tenta abrir um arquivo (utilizando o id da sessão como identificador) contendo as variáveis para preencher o array `$_SESSION` e caso não encontre nenhum arquivo, ele cria um novo. No final do script, o php salva todas as variáveis do array `$_SESSION` neste arquivo.

Como os cookies são compartilhados entre abas, o usuário terá apenas um id de sessão, ou seja, o php irá utilizar o mesmo arquivo de sessão para o usuário, independente da aba em que ele estiver. É aí que surge o seu problema, pois o php irá sobrescrever todas as informações que estiverem no arquivo de sessão pelos novos.

Uma solução para o seu problema seria utilizar identificadores por páginas, por exemplo:

```
$_SESSION['permissoes']['home'] = ...;
$_SESSION['permissoes']['usuario'] = ...;
```

Mas cuidado com a quantidade de informações que você armazenar. Muitos usuários online ao mesmo tempo contendo cada um uma sessão gigante não é uma boa idéia.